# Field with inner structure in Django

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, data-modeling, database-schema

I'd like to create a table of items in `Django`. The problem is that every
Item has different inner structure and I would have to create too many tables.

For example if item will be `CPU` I'd like to have the inner structure attribute (column) as follows:

```
type:processor
frequency:value
number of cores:value
socket:value
```

And if the item will be `smartphone` the inner structure would be:

```
type:smartphone
os:value
displaysize:value
cpuID:value
```

When adding new items to the database, the field should first ask the user what type he wants to add (e.g. CPU) and according to this infomation display the appropriate form
for the inner structure attribute which depends on type. Certain fields of the inner structure will be required but most of the will be optional and there are fields that can be multiple (e.g. multiple URLs).

What are the approaches to implement this? Is there already some help in `Django` for
such data? What are the pros and cons of various approaches?
So far, I see one disadvantage. Note that smartphone uses cpuID as a foreign key. Is it possible to preserve references? Note that CPU can have reference to it's manufacturer (only an example that various items can have a few references to other items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to create a "main" table with all the common properties and separate tables for each type of object. This is very easy to do in Django and model definitions look "clean", see [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for details.

Example models for your situation:

```
# Hold common fields/properties
class Item(models.Model):
    type = ...
    price = ...
    weight = ...
    width = ...
    height = ...
    ...

# Below are example classes which will inherit all properties from Item
class CPU(Item):
    frequency = ...
    core_count = ...
    socket = ...

class Smartphone(Item):
    os = ...
    display_size = ...
    cpu = models.ForeignKey(CPU, ...)  # Example linking between items.
```

Note that each "concrete" item consists of two database rows: the common table and in the "concrete" table. The two tables are joined by a one to one field in the "concrete" table (Django adds this field for you, but you can redefine it, if you want).

Example methods of retrieving items from database:

```
# Get all "base" items without touching type tables
Item.objects.all()

# Get all items along with their child properties. This is rather ugly and expensive.
Item.objects.select_related('cpu', 'smarthphone', ...).all()

# Gets smartphones, uses a join to retrieve data from two tables.
# I don't remeber if the `select_related` is required here.
Smartphone.objects.select_related('item').all()  

# When type of the item is only know at runtime, you can query like this (requires additional table column for storing type):
Item.objects.filter(type='smartphone')
# Or alternatively finding out which type class you want.
```

Advantages:

1. Class definitions look clean and simple.
2. Very close to optimal database structure.
3. One db query can retrieve items of various types.

Disadvantages:

1. Excessive joins when retrieving objects with full data.